# Why isn't there an interval typeclass in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, abstraction

Maybe I have not looked in the right place, but I could not find a type class for intervals in Haskell. It seems to me that this abstraction would be useful in many cases, since intervals are used in many domains.

This can also be seen in the amount of different packages on *hackage* that implement some sort of interval structure ([list of interval packages](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=intervals)).

Would it be to confusing to implement the different types of intervals (open, closed, ...) with type classes, or is there another concepts which helps me to build my own intervals except of an own data type?

Comment: why a type-class and not just a simple data-type (tuple?) with a set of   (constrained of course) functions operating on it? (well - just like the one from Mr. Kmett https://hackage.haskell.org/package/intervals-0.7.0.1/docs/Numeric-Interval.html ;) )

Comment: The main advantage would be, that it would work with different types? No code duplication for different types of bounds (`UTCTime`, `Int`,...) since the logic would remain the same. It would also fit in nicely with `Ord` and `Eq`.

Comment: @j.dog: all those interval types are _parameterised_ on the undelying field type, so you can just do `Interval Double`, `Interval UTCTime`, `Interval Int`... no need for classes at all.

Comment: I did not know that - this makes it really nice to use. As someone who is still learning, Haskell keeps on amazing me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`-XFunctionalDependences`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) and `-XFlexibleInstances` (to write any instances with this...). I've written some code below with comments to illustrate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

-- | Intervals with endpoints of type e.
class (Ord e) => Interval i e | i -> e where
  {-# MINIMAL inf, sup #-}
  -- lower bound ("infinimum") 
  inf :: i -> e
  -- upper bound ("supremum")
  sup :: i -> e

-- Is (X : Interval e) a valid Interval?
valid :: Interval i e => i -> Bool
valid x = sup x > inf x

-- Is (X : Interval e) an invalid Interval?
notValid :: Interval i e => i -> Bool
notValid = not . valid

-- Is (x : e) contained within (X : Interval e)
containsPoint :: Interval i e => i -> e -> Bool
x `containsPoint` p = p >= inf x && p <= sup x

-- Is (x : e) below (X : Interval e)
abovePoint :: Interval i e => i -> e -> Bool
x `abovePoint` p = p < inf x

-- Is (x : e) above (X : Interval e)
belowPoint :: Interval i e => i -> e -> Bool
x `belowPoint` p = p > sup x

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x < y iff sup X < inf Y 
before :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `before` y = sup x < inf y

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x > y iff inf X > sup Y 
after :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `after` y = inf x > sup y

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x == y iff (inf X == inf Y) && (sup X == sup Y)
equals :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `equals` y = inf x == inf y && sup x == sup y

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x /= y iff (sup x < inf y) || (inf x > sup y)
nequals :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `nequals` y = sup x < inf y || inf x > sup y

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x <= y iff sup x <= inf y
eqBefore :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `eqBefore` y = sup x <= inf y

-- For all (x : e) in (X : Interval e), (y : e) in (Y : Interval e),
-- x >= y iff inf x >= sup y
eqAfter :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `eqAfter` y = inf x >= sup y

-- Does (X : Interval e) contain (Y : Interval e)?
contains :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
x `contains` y = inf x <= inf y && sup y <= sup x

-- Is (X : Interval e) a subset of (Y : Interval e)?
isSubSetOf :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool
isSubSetOf = flip contains

-- Do (X : Interval e) and (Y : Interval e) overlap?
overlaps :: Interval i e => i -> i -> Bool 
x `overlaps` y = inf x <= sup y && sup x >= inf y

instance (Ord e) => Interval (e,e) e where
  inf (a,_) = a
  sup (_,b) = b

instance (Ord a) => Interval [a] a where
  inf = minimum
  sup = maximum

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ inf ["one","two","three"] -- will print "one"
  putStrLn $ sup ("first","second")    -- will print "second"
```

However, as commenters have pointed out, This is pretty unnecessary. It's probably better to have something like an `Interval` datatype and just have `Interval Double`, `Interval Int`, etc. I recommend the [intervals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intervals) package.